# Magento add new Button on Sales order view

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I want to add new Button on Sales order view page. I created below mention code

observer file

```
<?php

class Ar_Orderstatus_Model_Observer
{

    public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

            $block->addButton('rto', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                    'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

           $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
            array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  
        }
    }
}
```

controller file

```
<?php

class Ar_Orderstatus_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
        Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        return $order;
    }


public function testAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->setState('rto', true)
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }

}






}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow bellow steps

Step : 1 app\etc\modules\AR_Orderstatus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AR_Orderstatus>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </AR_Orderstatus>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step : 2 app\code\local\AR\Orderstatus\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AR_Orderstatus>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </AR_Orderstatus>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
    <orderstatus>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>AR_Orderstatus</module>
            <frontName>orderstatus</frontName>
        </args>
    </orderstatus>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <orderstatus_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>AR_Orderstatus_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addOrderstatusAction</method>
                    </orderstatus_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <orderstatus>
                <class>AR_Orderstatus_Model</class>
            </orderstatus>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step : 3 app\code\local\AR\Orderstatus\controllers\Adminhtml\IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Ar_Orderstatus_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
        Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        return $order;
    }


    public function rtoAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->setState('rto', true)
                    ->save();
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }

    }

    public function shipmentAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->setState('shipment', true)
                    ->save();
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }

    }
}
```

Step : 4 app\code\local\AR\Orderstatus\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php

class Ar_Orderstatus_Model_Observer
{

    public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

            $block->addButton('rto', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                    'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

           $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
            array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your step but no change

Comment: What are issues?

Comment: Button not display on order view page

Comment: Updated ans pls check now

Comment: Button is working but state didn't chage?

Comment: but need to add state change code in file app\code\local\AR\Orderstatus\controllers\Adminhtml\IndexController.php

Comment: can you send you state name your created

Comment: Ya i already created how to i add in IndexController.php

Comment: test only i want to create custome state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32716/discussion-between-abdul-and-kothari).

Comment: How to add a two state Action in IndexController.php

Comment: Need to add two action or order state?

Comment: i need a button called In shipement and Delivery

Comment: even that's two state

Comment: Yes it is possible. Need to add some code in your Observer file

Comment: can you please tell me how to add it

Comment: I added two button but last button only work

Comment: try this : $block->addButton('change_shipement', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipement'),
                'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/test')}')",
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));

Comment: and second:

$block->addButton('change_delivery', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Delivery'),
                'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/test')}')",
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));

Comment: Both are not woking it redirect to 404

Comment: Check my updated question i add observer and controller file

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: ass & also vote me

Comment: i already up voted you

Comment: HI @Abdul 1st i change rto state after that i click shipement it redirect to 404 page

Comment: In your Observer file replace code from $block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment') to $block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/shipment')

Comment: working now right?

Comment: Ya it's working

Answer (score 4):

Both answers are not wrong but would trigger on each layout or widget load.
The best solution is to add an Event for

```
controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view
```

config.xml of your module:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view>
            <observers>
                <module_button>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>addButtonOfYourChoice</method>
                </module_button>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

in your Namespace_Module_Model_Observer:

```
/**
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function addButtonOfYourChoice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('sales_order_edit');
    if (!$block) {
        return $this;
    }
    $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
    $url   = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl(
        "adminhtml/yourmoduleurl/youraction",
        array('order_id' => $order->getId())
    );
    $block->addButton(
        'button_id',
        array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('namespace_module')->__('Button Label'),
            'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $url . '\')',
            'class'   => 'go'
        )
    );
    return $this;
}
```

now in your action your can trigger, change, manipulate whatever you want

Regards

Comment: This needs to be accepted as the correct answer as this is the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

app/etc/modules/Solsint_Cancelorder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Solsint_Cancelorder>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Solsint_Cancelorder>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Solsint/Cancelorder/etc/config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Solsint_Cancelorder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Solsint_Cancelorder>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
          <cancelorder>
            <class>Solsint_Cancelorder_Model</class>
          </cancelorder>
        </models>
     <events>
      <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                    <class>cancelorder/Observer</class>
                    <method>sendreviewEmailOnComplete</method>
                </sales_order_save_commit_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
    </events>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>  
        <events>
          <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                        <class>Solsint_Cancelorder_Model_Observer</class>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <method>addbuttoninorder</method>
                    </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        </events>
     </adminhtml> 
</config>
```

in your observer class 
app/code/local/Solsint/Cancelorder/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Solsint_Cancelorder_Model_Observer{


public function sendreviewEmailOnComplete($observer)
{ 
    $order = $observer->getOrder();Mage::log('working');
    if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
    { Mage::log('working');
     $comment='';
     $orderload=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getEntityId());
     $orderload->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, $comment);
    }
}
  public function addbuttoninorder($event)
{ Mage::log("adadadasd");

    $block = $event->getBlock();


    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');
        $block->addButton('change_status', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Change status'),

            'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('modulename/path/')}')",

            'class'     => 'go'
        ));

    }

}
}

?>
```

Comment: can you please tell me the path name also

Comment: follow my last answer and xml after the </global> tag and observer is also there just add function

Comment: can i add config.xml & Observer.php

Comment: no just ad xml in config.xml that are already don't need to create new. also for observer just add method in that

Comment: Sorry really i didn't get exact path

Comment: do you have code of my last answer? open  `app/code/local/Solsint/Cancelorder/etc/config.xml` add above xml code after </global> tag

Comment: I added but button is not created in order view

Comment: can you paste the updated code in your question?

Comment: Yes i changed but no luck

Comment: i check my code and this updated working code follow it..

Comment: I used your code but no button showing on order view

Comment: clear your cache and check any spelling mistake in directory name.

Comment: My cache is alwayz diabled only there is no spell mistake /configx.xml you put this so i changed config.xml